# Why is the function in my Javascript code executing right away but not when I click the button?

Tags: javascript, button

I am having trouble understanding why the text is not changing when I click the button. It is being executed right away when the page starts instead. I am not sure why this is happening because I told it to only execute when you click on the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="all">
<head>
    <head>
    </head>
    <title>Lab8</title>

    <style></style>

    </head>

<body>
<script>
    var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
    iDiv.id = 'block';
    iDiv.className = 'block';
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
    iDiv.style.backgroundColor = "#d79365";
    iDiv.style.padding = "40px";

    var innerDiv2 = document.createElement('div');
    innerDiv2.className = 'block-3';

    iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv2);
    innerDiv2.style.padding = "40px";
    innerDiv2.style.textAlign = "center";
    innerDiv2.innerHTML = "Here is changing the text: ";
    //innerDiv2.innerHTML = "Text Change when button clicked";
    //innerDiv2.style.textAlign = "center";



    // Now create and append to iDiv
    var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    innerDiv.className = 'block-2';

    // The variable iDiv is still good... Just append to it.
    iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
    innerDiv.innerHTML = "I'm the inner div";
    innerDiv.style.padding = "40px";
    innerDiv.style.backgroundColor = "#eac67a";

    var ClickButton = document.createElement('button');
    ClickButton.className = 'block-4';
    iDiv.appendChild(ClickButton);
    ClickButton.innerHTML = "Style";
    ClickButton.style.margin = "auto";
    ClickButton.style.display = "block";
    ClickButton.style.width = "80px";
    ClickButton.style.height = "50px";
    ClickButton.style.top = "50px";
    ClickButton.style.backgroundColor = "#233237";
    ClickButton.style.color = "white";

    function js_style(){
        alert("hi");
        document.querySelector("innerDiv2");
        innerDiv2.style.fontSize = 'large';
        innerDiv2.style.font = 'italic bold 20px arial,serif';
        innerDiv2.style.color = "#eac67a";
    };

    document.getElementsByTagName('button').onclick = js_style();

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You have already correctly used `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]` (although `document.body` is shorter). Why do you still have a mistake at `document.getElementsByTagName('button').onclick`? `document.getElementsByTagName` doesn’t return a single element.

Comment: you create the button `ClickButton` ... use `ClickButton.addEventListener('click', js_style)` and forget the old school "onclick" rubbish

Comment: Please remove the unnecessary bits, like all the style stuff-it's hard to see what's important.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByTagName('button') returns a HTMLCollection.
Setting the 'onclick' value of the HTMLCollection does not set the 'onclick' handle of the button.

i could get the example to work by giving the button an id and retrieving the button via that id (rather than it's tag name):
https://jsfiddle.net/0L1kj3ja/

```
var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
    iDiv.id = 'block';
    iDiv.className = 'block';
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
    iDiv.style.backgroundColor = "#d79365";
    iDiv.style.padding = "40px";

    var innerDiv2 = document.createElement('div');
    innerDiv2.className = 'block-3';

    iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv2);
    innerDiv2.style.padding = "40px";
    innerDiv2.style.textAlign = "center";
    innerDiv2.innerHTML = "Here is changing the text: ";
    //innerDiv2.innerHTML = "Text Change when button clicked";
    //innerDiv2.style.textAlign = "center";



    // Now create and append to iDiv
    var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    innerDiv.className = 'block-2';

    // The variable iDiv is still good... Just append to it.
    iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
    innerDiv.innerHTML = "I'm the inner div";
    innerDiv.style.padding = "40px";
    innerDiv.style.backgroundColor = "#eac67a";

    var ClickButton = document.createElement('button');
    ClickButton.id = 'btn';
    ClickButton.className = 'block-4';
    iDiv.appendChild(ClickButton);
    ClickButton.innerHTML = "Style";
    ClickButton.style.margin = "auto";
    ClickButton.style.display = "block";
    ClickButton.style.width = "80px";
    ClickButton.style.height = "50px";
    ClickButton.style.top = "50px";
    ClickButton.style.backgroundColor = "#233237";
    ClickButton.style.color = "white";

    function js_style(){
        alert("hi");
        document.querySelector("innerDiv2");
        innerDiv2.style.fontSize = 'large';
        innerDiv2.style.font = 'italic bold 20px arial,serif';
        innerDiv2.style.color = "#eac67a";
    };

    document.getElementById('btn').onclick = js_style;
```

Comment: And the explanation for the second change you've made?

Comment: I'm talking about the missing `()`

Comment: and, just for fun, and who knows why, but by adding an id, you can do `document.getElementsByTagName('button').btn.onclick = js_style;` !!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that `getElementsByTagName` returns a HTMLCollection - which behaves a little like an array, in that you can access the individual elements using array syntax like `x[0]`

However, as you're creating the button dynamically, you can dispense with that, and, in the process, dispense with last millennium code `element.onclick=rubbish`

```
var ClickButton = document.createElement('button');
ClickButton.addEventListener('click', js_style);
```

done

Answer (score 0):

instead of 
`document.getElementsByTagName('button').onclick = js_style();`
try this :

```
 var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++)
{
buttons[i].onclick = js_style;
}
```

when you use `js_style();` javascript will call that function so you should just introduce your function name to `.onclick`

Comment: @user2891660 how about my new approach?

Comment: you still don't get what `getElementsByTagName` returns ... hint: elementS

Comment: @JaromandaX i edited my answer. i think it would work now, am i right?

Answer (score 0):

You were attaching `onclick` event to collection of JS nodes. I've refactored your code and added one more class to `button` element to attach`click` event on that.

It is always advisable to add class with `js` prefix to attach event handler to DOM elements. In this way,no one will mess with `js-*` classes.

```js
//create outer div and apply styles
var outerDiv = document.createElement('div');
var outerDivStyle = 'background-color:#d79365;padding: 40px;';
outerDiv.id = 'block';
outerDiv.className = 'block';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(outerDiv);
outerDiv.style.cssText = outerDivStyle;

//create inner div and apply styles
var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
innerDiv.className = 'block-3';

outerDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
var innerDivStyle = 'padding: 40px;text-align:center;';
innerDiv.innerHTML = "Here is changing the text: ";
innerDiv.style.cssText = innerDivStyle;



//create last div and apply styles
var lastDiv = document.createElement('div');
lastDiv.className = 'block-2';

// The variable iDiv is still good... Just append to it.
outerDiv.appendChild(lastDiv);
lastDiv.innerHTML = "I'm the inner div";
var lastDivStyle = 'background-color:#eac67a;padding: 40px;';
lastDiv.style.cssText = lastDivStyle;


//create button
var clickButton = document.createElement('button');
clickButton.id = 'js-btn';
clickButton.className = 'block-4';
outerDiv.appendChild(clickButton);
var btnStyles = 'background-color:#233237;color: white;margin:auto;display:block;width: 80px; height:50px;';
lastDiv.style.cssText = lastDivStyle;
clickButton.innerHTML = "Style";
clickButton.style.cssText = btnStyles;

function jsStyle() {
  alert("hi");
  document.querySelector("innerDiv");
  innerDiv.style.fontSize = 'large';
  innerDiv.style.font = 'italic bold 20px arial,serif';
  innerDiv.style.color = "#eac67a";
};

document.querySelector('#js-btn').onclick = jsStyle;
```

Comment: _“It is always advisable to add class with `js` prefix to attach event handler to DOM elements. In this way, you will increase performance a bit and no one will mess with `js-*` classes.”_ — Citation needed.

Comment: This is from my personal knowledge.Though, you might find these articles useful. 

More about prefixes is here - https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/06/battling-bem-extended-edition-common-problems-and-how-to-avoid-them/

I couldn't find any citation for performance of selector so editing it.